# Order detail with product id

Tags: admin, orders

How can i display product id in the admin order details page.]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need modify the file -

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml
```

You can use following code to get the product Id -

```
$_item->getId();
```

Comment: Overwriting that file is essentially a core modification and will be reverted in an upgrade.

Comment: @philwinkle if used in conjunction with an admin theme - for example using http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-admin-theme-in-magento/ and copying the above file to your theme this has merits.

Comment: @Fooman absolutely. however, the suggested method as-is will overwrite the core file. No downvote or anything - just for posterity / future Googlers.

Comment: I would like to point out that the above answer WILL NOT Return the Product ID?! What vote it up?

Answer (score 1):

[image]You will need $_item->getProductId() for the product id. $_item->getId() will only return the row id of that item.

And I would agree with Phil not to update this file

Comment: FTFY: `$this->__('Product ID:')`